# Why ifelse function doesn't display vector as output in R

Tags: r

I use `R` and run the following comands

```
x = c(1,2,3)
y = c(4,5,6)
s = rbinom(1,1,0.5)
ifelse(s==1,x,y)
```

However, when I run it instead of getting the whole vectors on each case, I just get back the first element of the vector. How do I solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `if/else` here

```
if(s == 1) x else y
```